# CA Agile Central (RALLY) How to Import multiple User Stories with Parent relationship?

Tags: rest, api, rally, ca-api-gateway

I would like to upload multiple User Stories to Rally with specifying Parent relationship using either Actions>Import User Stories> and CSV file or even better with API

Tried adding it to the upload csv Template as "Parent", "Parent ID", "Feature" and even "HierarchicalRequirement_Feature__refObjectUUID", "HierarchicalRequirement_Feature__ref"

Found this but getting loads of errors

$ curl -X POST \ https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement/create \ -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \ -H 'zsessionid: _abcdefg' \ -d '{ "hierarchialrequirement": { "Name": "Test US", "Project": "project/326535946857", "Description": "Test US" , "PortfolioItem": { "_ref": "portfolioitem/feature/F133020", "_type": "PortfolioItem/Feature" }' curl: (1) Protocol " https" not supported or disabled in libcurl curl: (3) Host name ' -H' contains bad letter curl: (3) Port number ended with ' ' curl: (3) Host name ' -H' contains bad letter curl: (3) Port number ended with ' ' curl: (3) Host name ' -d' contains bad letter curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 29

Comment: Welcome to SO. could you provide a [MCVE] please. Th emore specific you are in your question, the more you have chance to have a feedback: see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, You actually cannot import relationships into Rally using the standard UI as I found out. You can do it with the Excel Plugin.
But I want this to be automated. If plugin can do it I am sure there is a code I can use for this specific Parent part. If someone could help I would be very greatful. Found this but getting loads of errors

$ curl -X POST \ https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement/create \ -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \ -H 'zsessionid: _abcdefg' \ -d '{ "hierarchialrequirement": { "Name": "Test US", "Project": "project/326535946857", "Description": "Test US" , "PortfolioItem": { "_ref": "portfolioitem/feature/F133020", "_type": "PortfolioItem/Feature" }'
curl: (1) Protocol " https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
curl: (3) Host name ' -H' contains bad letter
curl: (3) Port number ended with ' '
curl: (3) Host name ' -H' contains bad letter
curl: (3) Port number ended with ' '
curl: (3) Host name ' -d' contains bad letter
curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 29